# How to describe Option[FiniteDuration] in proto with scalapb

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I am trying to use proto3 and scalapb, but I am unable to map `FiniteDuration` as well as unable to use it as `Option`. Can anyone please advise on the same

```
case class Message(id:Int , interval: Option[FiniteDuration])
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does the .proto look like for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you configured your scalabp in sbt as described in [installation guide](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/installation)

You need to define a [custom type](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations#custom-types) for a field to be converted from `int64`, mapped by default as `Long`, into `FiniteDuration`

For example:

```proto
syntax="proto3";

import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";

option java_package = "my.app.proto";

message Message {
  int32 id = 1;
  optional int64 interval = 2 [(scalapb.field).type = "scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration"];
}
```

This will generate a case class that looks what you need.

ScalaPB will rely on implicit resolution to compile this and apply mapping from `Long` to `FiniteDuration`. For this you need to define a `scalapb.TypeMapper[Long, FiniteDuration]` in `package object` of the same package where case class is generated, ie `my.app.proto.message`.

```scala
package my.app.proto

import scalapb.TypeMapper

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration

package object message {
  implicit val finiteDuration: TypeMapper[Long, FiniteDuration] =
    TypeMapper[Long, FiniteDuration](s => FiniteDuration.apply(s, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))(_.toMillis)
}
```

Comment: All fields are `optional` in `proto3` so no need to specify it.

Comment: @Tim This is correct from protocol point of view but there is a difference in a case class. When `optional` is used, it will wrap a primitive with Scala `Option` and set default to `None`. Otherwise, the type of field will be of a primitive with a default value of primitive, for example `timeout: Long = 0` vs `timeout: Option[Long] = None`

Comment: Ooh, didn't know that. Very helpful, thanks!